# How to compare 2 different sets of data in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have 2 arrays, the first consists of ~2000 elements.

The second array contains ~500 arrays with 2 elements in each.

I need a way to check if the elements in the second array exists within the first array, and if so, construct a new array of the matching elements.

```
ex)

array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

array2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,14],[9,11]] 

new_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11]
```

I want to do this without having to loop through all the elements in either arrays.

What would be the most efficient way to do this? Would the performance improve if I implemented them as hashes as opposed to arrays?

Comment: The first element of `array2` is `[1,2]`. Must both `1` and `2` be in `array1` for `1` and `2` to be in `new_array` (assuming no other elements of`array2` contain a `1` or `2`)? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: Can we assume that the arrays and subarray are always sorted? If that is the case this could be solved in `O(n+m)`, but the implementation will be more complex.

Comment: @spickermann yes, you can assume that they've been sorted.

Comment: Where does this data come from, do you have control over the implementation? Did you consider using a `Set` instead of an Array? Can you please add your current implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the second array and than use [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-26) (intersection):

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
array2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

new_array = array1 & array2.flatten
#=> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This version uses Ruby idioms and is very readable. The performance depends on the implementation of the intersection method in Ruby. I don't know the implementation, but would guess that it uses a Hash internally. So we would end up with building a new array in `flatten` (`O(m)`), plus building the Hash structure (`O(n)` on average), plus the comparison (`O(m)`).

If we can assume that both arrays and the subarray (*!*) are always sorted, than you might want to iterate manually through this arrays. This will do maximum of `O(m + n)` steps and might be slightly faster than the intersection version, because there is no need to flatten the array first and no need to calculate hashes for each value.

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
array2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

index1 = 0
index2 = [0, 0]

intersection = []

loop do
  break intersection if index1 >= array1.size || index2[0] >= array2.size

  if array1[index1] == array2[index2[0]][index2[1]]
    intersection << array1[index1]
    index1 += 1
    index2 = index2[1] == 0 ? [index2[0], 1] : [index2[0] + 1, 0]

  elsif array1[index1] < array2[index2[0]][index2[1]]
    index1 += 1

  else
    index2 = index2[1] == 0 ? [index2[0], 1] : [index2[0] + 1, 0]  
  end
end
```

You might want to benchmark both versions. For readability reasons I would prefer the first version.

Comment: Excellent answer. AFAIK, your complexity analysis for set intersection is correct.